# Extracting columns from a 2d numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2d numpy array:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],
              [4,5,6,7]])
```

How can I extract the following array?

```
result = array([[3,4],
               [6,7]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is called `slicing` , you can use `<array>[<row indexes>,<column indexes>]`.

Example -

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],
              [4,5,6,7]])

print(a[:,2:])
>>> [[3 4]
     [6 7]]
```